# Create New DirectShow Filter with VisualStudio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, filter, directshow

I need to create new filter with one input and two outputs.

The filter sends ping (from output 1), receives the ping back (from the input) and accordingly sends some value (to output 2).

I already have the code for the ping, but I need to combine the code with the new filter.

I tried very hard to find an example for my needs but with no success.

It will be great if someone knows how to do so, or lead me to good tutorial.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "ping"? DirectShow is for Video and Audio. If you have Input and Output Pins, then you have a [Transform Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391015(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Hi, i need to measure rtt with ping, and accordingly change something on the video. my first goal is to succeed send ping from that module in graphedit- meaning: include all the libraries needed and send ping..

can i write module that not connected to anything?
if not- how can i see the code of spesific filter of DirectShow's filters?

thanks!

Comment: Whatever you do ping for, it might be fine (or might be not). But putting it up onto a dedicated filter pin is most likely to be a wrong approach. While this is possible on its own, it just can't be made right if you ask how to do it from the start.